# Is there any straightforward way to evaluate a recursive function breadth-first?

Tags: haskell

Mind the following program:

```hs
foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
foo n x | x == n    = True
foo n x | otherwise = foo n (x * 2) || foo n (x * 2 + 1)

main :: IO ()
main = print (foo 10 0)
```

It implements a function `foo` that calls itself recursively in two branches, increasing the second argument as it recurses down the tree. It "should" return `True` if its second argument ever becomes equal to the first, which is the case, because `((0 * 2 + 1) * 2 + 1) * 2 == 10`. But that doesn't happen, because Haskell gets stuck trying to evaluate the left branch depth-first.

Usually, this would be solved by implementing a BFS, but doing that is awkward in Haskell. I wonder if there is any automated, or at least less-obtrusive way to evaluate a recursive function breadth-first?

Comment: There is no way a function can be evaluated in a way it is not written. Your function is basically "terminate if terminates for this, or terminates for that", which is a *halting problem*. It is undecidable. I don't see how you will solve it with BFS without changing the conditions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's not related to the halting problem. This function would evaluate to true if Haskell always reduced outermost redexes first, instead of leftmost-innermost.

Comment: Would it? Maybe. For this specific input. Will it for any input? This is what the halting problem is about.

Comment: I'm not asking that though, I'm merely asking if there is any way to evaluate a Haskell function breadth first (be it through a compiler flag, or an user-friendly DSL). Point is that specifying a recursive function is easier than manually setting up a BFS, so a library or feature for that would be handy.

Comment: @EugeneSh.- the halting problem in general is of course undecidable, but which inputs this algorithm terminates on is eminently decidable. You can stop the recursion as soon as both of the branches get bigger than `n` [And you could easily use this fact to write a version of this function that will always terminate - although it wouldn't be a "breadth first search".]

Comment: What you're talking about is not "breadth first". There is no meaning in saying that Haskell should evaluate operator `||` before any of its arguments, nor that it should evaluate both arguments "simultaneously" rather than left to right. What you're really sort of implying here is that it would be nice, for this specific program, if the execution proceeded right-to-left rather than left-to-right. Sure, it could have been the case, but then it would just be equally inconvenient for you if you happened to swap the arguments of `||`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That would be the change of the algorithm. Moreover, this specific instance of a problem is decidable analytically, but a similar problem can be easily presented based on say.. Collatz conjecture - and then it is not solvable analytically too.

Comment: Anyway, it's about the order of evaluation of the `||` operator and only. Unrelated to BFS or DFS.

Comment: No, it's not about the order of evaluation, as I understand it. If you're testing `A || B`, and `A` gives rise to `C || D` and `B` to `E || F`, Haskell will execute the above code by going "depth-first" through `A`, `C` and whatever comes next - if this branch doesn't terminate, it will never get as far as evaluating `B`. Whereas the OP, quite reasonably, is asking whether it's possible to write the code so that `A` and `B` are BOTH tested (order is irrelevant), then `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, and so on.

Comment: @RobinZigmond No, the OP is asking if there is a way to make the *given* code execute differently.

Comment: Well that's how I understood it, but let's wait for the OP to clarify. The question I thought he was asking is quite interesting, anyway :) (And I don't know how to solve it, although as I said it's easy enough to rewrite this function so it always terminates, but that wouldn't work for more subtle cases where "breadth-first" might be helpful.)

Comment: btw thenjecture is quite different as far as I can see, because there is just one chain of computation. Of course it's unknown if it terminates (at 1) for every starting value. But there is no question of what "evaluation strategy" one can follow, because all you can do, given a value, is compute the next one in the chain. [Of course there may be some clever mathematics allowing one to collapse several steps into one, but still, it's a one-way process, very different from the question here.]

Comment: It is not about order of evaluation of `||` in special, it is absolutely about reducing recursive functions breadth-first (outermost redexes first) or depth-first (innermost redexes first). Notice that, if you have an expression that produces an infinite tree of `||`s (like this one), and if `true` shows up anywhere in that tree, then if Haskell evaluated redexes outermost first, such expression would always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Changing the evaluation order of `||` wouldn't help in this case. The only difference is that Haskell would be stuck on the rightmost branches of the tree (rather than on the leftmost). The only way for this expression to evaluate to true is, as I said, by evaluating redexes in order of depth, i.e., never beta-reducing an expression if there is another redex at higher height.

Comment: Ah, @RobinZigmond explained precisely the point with a few examples above.

Comment: Just realised my latest comment (4 up from this one) got mangled for some reason, in a way that makes it incomprehensible - the start should be "btw the Collatz conjecture is quite different..."

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Collatz conjecture too, because I'm not asking for a solution of a problem (i.e., "does this program halt"), I'm merely asking if it is possible to change the evaluation order of Haskell (actually I'm asking if there is an existing DSL I can use, since GHC probably can't do that). It has nothing to do with answering the halting problem because changing Haskell's evaluation order in the way I proposed obviously doesn't guarantee all functions will magically halt, although this one in special (and similars) would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the original code work with minimal tweaks using the [unamb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.7/docs/Data-Unamb.html) package. The key observation is that the "platonic" `(||)` is symmetric in that it can short-circuit in either direction; and unamb gives you a way to realize that.

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
foo n x | x == n    = True
foo n x | otherwise = foo n (x * 2) `por` foo n (x * 2 + 1)
```

Works, but leaves a zombie behind running at 100% CPU:

```
> foo 10 1
True
```

That's probably a bug, though I don't feel super into chasing it down just now...

P.S. I'd probably prefer this spelling of `foo` if you decide to use unamb, just because it's syntactically more compact than using guards:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
foo n x = x == n || por (foo n (2*x)) (foo n (2*x+1))
```

Comment: Unamb is a lovely concept but it does tend to leave zombies around and otherwise be kind of performance-unstable.  I have been pondering about how to make it more predictable.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how (or if it's even possible) to generalize this, but you can simulate BFS by explicitly maintaining a queue of arguments to check.

```
import Data.Sequence

foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
foo n x = let foo' :: Seq Int -> Bool
              foo' Empty = False
              foo' (x' :<| xs')
                 | n' == x' = True
                 | otherwise = foo' (xs' >< fromList [2 * x', 2*x'+1])
          in foo' (singleton x)
```

Instead of recursing immediately, the argument(s) to the recursive calls are simply appended to the end of the queue. The helper checks each argument in first-come, first-served order. Since `n` never changes, I simply closed the helper over it. More generally, you could store tuples of arguments in the queue.

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
foo n x = let foo' :: Seq (Int, Int) -> Bool
              foo' Empty = False
              foo' ((n', x') :<| rest) 
                | n' == x' = True
                | otherwise = foo' (rest >< fromList [(n',(2*x')),(n',(2*x'+1)))
          in foo' (singleton (n, x))
```

Note that in this case, the queue will never be emptied, because (since the original function wasn't guaranteed to terminate) you are effectively searching an infinite tree. If the original recursion was guarded, then new argument(s) would only conditionally be added to the queue, allowing for the possibility that it would eventually be emptied.

Comment: I think you could add a guard `| y > n = False` so that it will terminate.

Comment: Probably, but I'm trying to keep this as general as possible so that it's more apparent how to apply it to other functions.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can directly produce the "levels" of the BFS. Merge the levels of parallel recursive calls. So:

```
import Data.List

foo :: Int -> Int -> [[Bool]]
foo n x = id
    . ([x == n] :)
    . map concat
    . transpose
    . map (foo n)
    $ [2*x, 2*x+1]
```

The outer list represents search depth -- depth 0 is in the 0th element, depth 1 in the 1th element, and so on -- while the inner lists contain the results of the function call on the arguments we explored at that level.

Summarizing into a single `Bool` just involves traversing both lists.

```
> any or (foo 10 1)
True
> any or (foo 1 10)
-- this might take a while
```

As a deforestation optimization, you could instead return just the `or` of each depth, thus:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> [Bool]
foo n x = (x == n) : zipWith (||) (foo n (2*x)) (foo n (2*x+1))
```

There is left only the list of depths; the inner lists from before are pre-collapsed. Still works okay:

```
> or (foo 10 1)
True
> or (foo 1 10)
-- uh oh...
```

Comment: I was going to propose tweaking the function to return the list of all tested `n`s, interleave the streams (with Omega or by hand -- I guess that's what your `transpose` is doing), then just take the first True in the merged stream of results. Or instead of Bools, make the stream of `[x | n==x]`s, `concat` it and `take 1`.

Comment: @WillNess Nice thought! [`(+++)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:-43--43--43-) can help.

Comment: thanks for the link. ah, it's your package, and it's got nice stuff in it! ... btw [`diagonal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:diagonal) is not really "unfair", it is much much fairer than `concat` !! :) so call it "slightly less fair", maybe? (tangentially, I wrote some very similar stuff to that, for [one chance answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97610/2909) of mine on CS.SE, where I did call the diagonal equivalent "fair" ... well, it's terminating!)

Answer (score 2):

Going

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
foo n x | x == n    = True
foo n x | otherwise = foo n (x * 2) || foo n (x * 2 + 1)
```

going..

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
foo n x =  x == n  || foo n (x * 2) || foo n (x * 2 + 1)
```

going...

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> [Bool]
foo n x = [x == n] ++ foo n (x * 2) ++ foo n (x * 2 + 1)
```

*going....*

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> [Bool]
foo n x = [x == n] ++ concat [foo n (x * 2) , foo n (x * 2 + 1)]
```

***Gone***!

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> [Bool]
foo n x = [x == n] ++ concat (transpose [foo n (x * 2) , foo n (x * 2 + 1)])
```

`takeWhile not $ foo 10 0` happily terminates after 20 steps. Easy to augment as needed.

`transpose` here emulates the diagonalization from the Omega package, achieving the interleaving of the two sub-streams of results.

If closer syntactic similarity is sought, define

```
xs ||/ ys = concat (transpose [xs, ys])

foo n x = [n==x] ||/ foo n (2*x) ||/ foo n (2*x+1)
```

`takeWhile not $ foo 10 0` stops after 25 steps.

This approach follows the principle of *explication*. Just as the implicit state changes of imperative programming are made explicit in functional programming, so can the steps of evaluation be explicated in a list, turning a fold into a scan (or unfold) so to speak.

---

NB: `(||/)` is the same as [`(+++)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:-43--43--43-) from Daniel Wagner's package [universe-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1), which has various enumeration tools. The utility of diagonalization can be seen e.g. in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97610/2909) of mine on CS.SE.